# Difference behind arraylist's remove and iterator's remove?

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I was looking at this code:

```
Iterator<String> itr = list1.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
if(list2.contains(itr.next())) 
itr.remove();
}
```

list1: a b c d 
list2: b c 
list1 becomes: a d

arraylist code (doesnt work)

```
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
if(list2.contains(list1.get(i)) 
list1.remove(i);
}
```

and it seems that iterator's remove method is different from arraylist's, which would shift every subsequent element to the left, making iterating and removing like this impossible (if something you wanted to remove appeared consecutively it would miss it, i believe). looking at the documentation didnt clear it up for me.

thank you!

Comment: Show us your [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) remove code.

Comment: sorry im very new to stackoverflow and i dont know how else to add on to my question, but i dont have actual arraylist code, just picture a for loop that iterates through an arraylist and removes upon hitting something you want to remove edit: HAHA yes i do

Comment: Do you see an "edit" below the question?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: You are basically pointing to the definition of a ConcurrentModificationException.  If you are iterating a list and you remove an item via anything other than iterator.remove() then the iterator will fail-fast with this exception.

Comment: i guess its why does iterator's remove method not cause subsequent elements of an arraylist to shift to the left?

Comment: thank you! after reading up on that and related questions it makes sense now

Comment: I would recommend adding your actual question by editing your original post.

Comment: Why do you say iterator.remove doesn't shift the elements?  If I run this it shifts just fine:

Answer (score 2):

Both the iterator's `remove` method and the `ArrayList`'s `remove` method shift elements to the left.  The difference is that when you use the iterator's `remove` method, the code in the iterator's `remove` knows how to fix things so that the iterator doesn't skip any elements.  When you use your own integer index and do the `remove` yourself, you have to manage the integer index yourself.  That is, you have to be aware that when the elements are shifted, you need to fix the index so that it doesn't skip any elements.

For example, this will work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {    
    if(list2.contains(list1.get(i)) {
        list1.remove(i);  
        i--;
    }  
}
```

although I do not like the practice of modifying index variables like this inside a `for` loop; because of that, I'd just use a `while` loop instead:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < list1.size()) {
    if(list2.contains(list1.get(i)) {
        list1.remove(i);  
    } else {
        i++;
    }  
}
```

That's a style issue, though.

Essentially, I think the iterator's `remove` method does something like this--i.e. it calls the ArrayList `remove` and then backs up the index by one.  However, I haven't looked at the actual source.